# How i get content of page using lxml-xml in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, utf-8, lxml

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


async def get_content(session,url):
    async with session.get(url) as responce:
            data = await responce.read()
    return BeautifulSoup(data.decode('utf-8'), 'lxml-xml')
    

async def parse(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_content(session,i)) for i in urls]
        soups = await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)
    return soups


url = "https://kolesa.kz/cars/almaty/?page={}"
urls = [url.format(i) for i in range(2,201)]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
soups = loop.run_until_complete(parse(urls))
loop.close()

print(soups[0])
```

Can not parse 200 page content of site using BeautifulSoup lxml-xml.
soups[0] shows this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.
Can i get html page using lxml-xml?

Answer (score 0):

The parser is `lxml-xml` [is equal to `xml` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). You probably don't want to parse the document as XML, but HTML. Change that to `lxml` (or `html5lib`/`html.parser`):

```
async def get_content(session,url):
    async with session.get(url) as responce:
            data = await responce.read()
    return BeautifulSoup(data.decode('utf-8'), 'lxml')  # <--- change to only `lxml`
```

Then the output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

...and so on.
```

Comment: but using lxml i lose speed of parsing.

lxml-xml parses 200 pages in 5 seconds
lxml parses in 50 seconds

Comment: @AggressiveGhosts That's because the `xml` parser doesn't parse the whole tree...it will see the document isn't valid XML and gives up. `lxml` will parse the whole document and of course, this takes more time. I would suggest to look at `multiprocessing` module then.